# How to save a copy of the current notebook without opening it?

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

I want to save a copy of the current notebook using Mathematica code

```
(* the notebook that's open is foo.nb *)
NotebookSave[SelectedNotebook[], "bar.nb"]
```

After execution, Mathematica would close `foo.nb` without saving, and open `bar.nb`. If I saved the path of `foo.nb`, close `bar.nb`, and reopen `foo.nb`, I would jump to the beginning of the file instead of having my cursor position saved.

How can I save a copy of `foo.nb` as `bar.nb` in the background, while still retaining my focus on `foo.nb`?

Answer (score 1):

Closing `foo.nb` when calling `NotebookSave` probably was a bug that was fixed (I use Mathematica 13.2). Currently the saved notebook `bar.nb` is opened in the background.

If you don't want to open `bar.nb` use `Export`:

```
Export[SelectedNotebook[], "bar.nb"]
```